# List down an array of messages from the converstions

Tags: vue.js, chat, v-for

I would like to list down the messages from a chat Id ... I am using Vue js and i could get the data but i am not able to display them using the component . anyone would like to guide ?

This is my message component where the messages will be displayed here

```
<template>
    <div class="row w-20 " >
        <div class="card col-4 ">
             <ul>
                <li v-for="(conversation,index) in conversation" :key="conversation.id">
                    <div >
                        {{message}}
                    </div>         
                    
                </li>
            </ul> 
            
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['conversation_index_route'],
    data() {
        return {
            conversations: [],
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation/'
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.$eventBus.$on('selectConversation', this.getConversations)
        this.getConversations();
    },
    methods: {
        getConversations(id) {
            console.log(this.url+id);
            axios.get(this.url+ id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.conversations = response.data;
                })
            
            
                
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This are the data that can seen in VUE .. I need to display the messages which is in array

```
conversation_index_route:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation"
conversations:Object
all_staff_attended:false
centre_id:5
children:"3828,4197,7748,11591,12376,12394,12433,12441,12754,12755,12765,13284,14149,14602,14656,14941"
classes:"139"
cover_image:"https://via.placeholder.com/150x150"
created_at:"2020-06-09 19:14:20"
exited_users:null
id:258
last_id:1917
messages:Array[5]
0:"{"_id":1921,"text":"Okayyyy","createdAt":"2020-06-10 01:46:10","user":{"_id":13077,"name":"Mom (Alex,Jacob,Ahmad,Patrick,Ethan Lim)","avatar":null},"image":null,"video":null,"file":null,"images":{},"public_id":null,"read":{"0":13077,"1":14083,"2":3}}"
1:"{"_id":1920,"text":"Chvfhdgy","createdAt":"2020-06-10 01:46:00","user":{"_id":13077,"name":"Mom (Alex,Jacob,Ahmad,Patrick,Ethan Lim)","avatar":null},"image":null,"video":null,"file":null,"images":{},"public_id":null,"read":{"0":13077,"1":14083,"2":3}}"
2:"{"_id":1919,"text":"Heyyyy","createdAt":"2020-06-10 01:45:28","user":{"_id":14083,"name":"Siti","avatar":"https:\/\/api.cloudinary.com\/v1_1\/ds13udsoy\/image\/download?timestamp=1592882587&public_id=archaana%2Flibrary%2Fprofile%2Fstaff%2Fcd3ecc89-f67e-4e5e-89e9-badafd903bba_1591032813&type=private&expires_at=1592882647&signature=d0f12d520d18ff1a6b594bcb0ecb742f8ffd88a6&api_key=567141618229528"},"image":null,"video":null,"file":null,"images":{},"public_id":null,"read":{"0":14083,"1":13077,"2":3}}"
3:"{"_id":1918,"text":"Hello","createdAt":"2020-06-10 01:45:14","user":{"_id":14083,"name":"Siti","avatar":"https:\/\/api.cloudinary.com\/v1_1\/ds13udsoy\/image\/download?timestamp=1592882587&public_id=archaana%2Flibrary%2Fprofile%2Fstaff%2Fcd3ecc89-f67e-4e5e-89e9-badafd903bba_1591032813&type=private&expires_at=1592882647&signature=d0f12d520d18ff1a6b594bcb0ecb742f8ffd88a6&api_key=567141618229528"},"image":null,"video":null,"file":null,"images":{},"public_id":null,"read":{"0":14083,"1":13077,"2":3}}"
4:"{"_id":1917,"text":"Hahaha","createdAt":"2020-06-10 01:14:34","user":{"_id":13077,"name":"Mom (Alex,Jacob,Ahmad,Patrick,Ethan Lim)","avatar":null},"image":null,"video":null,"file":null,"images":{},"public_id":null,"read":{"0":13077,"1":181,"2":14083,"3":3}}"
parent_users:"2413,3461,11690,11770,11786,12262,12263,13077,14232,15275,16713"
parents:Array[11]
staff_users:"321,16707,12117,13488,14083"
staffs:Array[5]
status_id:1
title:"Class 0906"
updated_at:"2020-06-09 19:14:20"
url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation/"
```

Can Anyone help me how to display the array of message in the component ..

Comment: can you console.log the conversation? what is return in response.data?

Comment: heyy . i get the URL .. http://127.0.0.1:8000/comms/conversation/240 .. 240 is the conversation id ..

Comment: no one can access your localhost. can you console.log(response.data) in the 'then' callback

Comment: i am receiving the data in the conversation ...

Comment: all_staff_attended: (...)
centre_id: (...)
children: (...)
classes: (...)
cover_image: (...)
created_at: (...)
exited_users: (...)
id: (...)
last_id: (...)
messages: (...)
parent_users: (...)
parents: (...)
staff_users: (...)
staffs: (...)
status_id: (...)
title: (...)
updated_at: (...)

Comment: maybe you update your post with this data?

Comment: then your conversation is not an array? Do you want only the messages only from your response?

Comment: its like there is an array of conversation(chat) .. so now i need to display the messages from each of the conversation.. where the message is also in array becs it was send by few user

Answer (score 0):

Alright let's assume that this is how your response is structured:

```
{
  all_staff_attended: false,
  centre_id: 5,
  messages: Array[5]
  ...etc.
}
```

Then when you call your `getConversations` method you could make your data property `this.conversations` equal to messages array from your response:

```
getConversations(id) {
     console.log(this.url+id);
     axios.get(this.url+ id)
     .then(response => {
        //from your response you would want to get messages array
        this.conversations = response.data.messages;
     })             
}
```

Once you got your messages array, you can then loop through it with `v-for` like so:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="(conversation,index) in conversation" :key="conversation.id">
      <div>
          <p>Message: {{conversation.text}}</p>
          <p>User: {{conversation.user.name}}</p>
          <p>Created at: {{conversation.createdAt}}</p>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now, you can access each object of the messages array like in the example above.